# Text in <button> not showing or shifted out of button

Tags: html, css, button, text

I have some issues with the text inside two of my buttons located inside a **block_head** class div.

In **Chrome**, they show exactly as I want :

[image: Buttons in Chrome]

In **IE9**, there is no text :

[image: Buttons in IE9]

Here's my **CSS** code :

```
.block .block_head button {
    margin: 13px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    float: right;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I tried playing with the CSS attributes (vertical-align, remove margin, etc.), and the best I could come up with is by removing the padding line :

[image: Buttons in IE9 almost correct]

I sense a stupid mistake or compatibility problem, as I am kind of new to web programming.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you replicate in a jsFiddle?

Comment: I'll try to replicate this section in jsFiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code, all I can imagine is that there is a style being applied that is setting the line height.  Can you try adding this to your ".block .block_head button" style?

```
line-height: 1em;
padding: 0px;
```

Comment: I guess you were right, that did the trick! I still have no idea what was causing this text shifting though.

Anyways, thanks for the solution, you made me discover a new useful attribute!

Comment: Cool!  Glad it worked.  Line-height basically adds spacing above and below your text.  You can find out more about it here: [line-height](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.block {
    float: right;
}

.block .block_head button {
    margin-right: 13px;
    padding: 2px 15px;
    // float: right; (button is an inline element)
    // height: 30px; (auto height)
    // text-align: center; (no fixed width, the text will always be in the center)
}
```